# Can you not call dismissModalViewController in succession?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal view controller where a user enters information. When they hit a submit button, that information is sent to the server and the modal view controller is dismissed.

However, if the user isn't signed in, when they click submit, it loads a sign in screen (as another modal view controller). After signing in, the sign in view controller is dismissed, their information is sent to the server, and the view controller is dismissed. The problem is, the view controller where they entered information remains on the screen.

I can fix the problem by delaying the dismissal of the data entry view controller. It seems that if I dismiss two view controllers quickly together, the second one remains.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Can you show the code how you are dismissing the two modalViewControllers? Possibly, the first controller is dismissed and released before it can dismiss its child controller.

Comment: So if the first login fails, then the first modal login view stays and another, second, modal login view is placed on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've determined the problem is caused because the first modal dismissed (the sign in view controller) doesn't disappear before I dismiss the second modal (the data entry view controller). When the second dismiss call occurs, the sign in view controller is still considered the top view controller, so nothing happens to the second VC.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as you are just presenting new modalView from previous controller.
You are not dismissing the previous controller.

you need to dismiss the controller from where you are launching Login controller.
you need to keep the pointer to your "info" controller accessible and on submit success on Login, you need to dismiss info controller as well like from LoginController or appDelegate (wherever you could keep the pointer accessible):

```
[info dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```